# Android imageview touch listener not working

Tags: java, android, imageview, clicklistener

Help me guys , My Imageview touch listener not working.

```
       imgShowNewAgain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and my XML Code is

```
     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <com.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/cstmEdtNewAgain"
                    style="@style/label_text_primary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/not_black_more"
                    android:hint="@string/new_password"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_padding"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/most_min_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/most_min_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_padding"
                    android:typeface="normal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                    app:font="@string/montserrat_regular"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgShowNewAgain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/showpasswordAgain"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/show" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Help will be appreciated.

**I have updated complete XML layout. The only layout iam  having is above xml. and i have initialize the layout and create the touchlistener for the Imageview. but event it is not working. i dont know where i made the mistake. or  is there need to add some additional information on xml file. like , focusable=false etc..**

Comment: Whats the problem?? any error?

Comment: No Error. it doesn't fire the listener.

Comment: Can you post your some more code?

Comment: Touch listener are working fine...
might be problem because of that two lines ..
cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());

Answer (score 1):

You implement the onTouchListener like this also:

> imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.img1: // example id
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.img2: // example id
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ya it is also work but i am just giving another way to do.

Comment: ok put log in your event so i think it is working but some problem in cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()); this line

Comment: cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()); this functionality working fine while onclicklistener

Comment: ya ok bt put Log in event nd let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
try this and make log point in all case.
        imgShowOld.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            cstmEdtNewPasswordAgain.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer everybody said is correct.  I think that you might have problem in your code. I mean, not the listener code. Are you try to handle the any other views like linearlayout listener.  That listener is disturbing you imageview.  Like , suppose you try to hide the keyboard programmatically when the particular view focused.  The same problem I have faced when I was toddle in android.  Check that.  Happy coding.

Comment: Yes . i am hide the keyboard when the focus changed from edittext. i will try it.

Comment: Perfect. i removed the hide functionality , now working fine. thanks a lot. I will upvote when i got upvote reputation. thank you.

Comment: Ok.  Happy coding.